# Menu icon and Back button color of Toolbar wont change on 4.2.2 android

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-design-library

I have an android app which works perfectly on kitkat and above versions of android. I was testing my app on android 4.2.2 and i found this design problem in my app. The back button and the menu overflow button colors won't change to white. 
These are the screenshots of my app from 4.2.2 mobile

[image: When search clicked]

[image: Normal toolbar]

Here is my style.xml

```
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_img</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>


</style>

<style name="AppBaseTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>
<style name="AppBaseTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />


<style name="AppBaseTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

and here is implementation of my toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppBaseTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

and in manifest im using theme `@style/AppBaseTheme.NoActionBar` on the activities.

Please tell me where is the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try setting AppBarOverlay as the theme on your Toolbar in xml? android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme.AppBarOverlay"

Comment: yes tried that too .. doesn't work

Comment: did you try app:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme.AppBarOverlay"

Comment: yes tired that too ... both app:theme or android:theme doesnt seems to work